# Android libgdx how to avoid static method and enum

Tags: java, android, enums, libgdx

Ok, now I'm truly mad and confusing. I've start a small project on Android with libgdx and I've been working two days to learn that the asset manager should not be static for some reason. I've also try the singleton option but there is a static getInstance method that bother me. I'm not sure it ok to have a static method instead a the asset manager class.

[Managing your assets](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets)

So I found out some good solution on here that was telling me to use an enum instead for this purpose. I've never use one before so I studdied that for another day until tonight I found this video that tell me to avoid enum on Android.

[The price of ENUMS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE)

Is there another alternative? Or am I getting something wrong with these two sources? I'm kinda of new to Android libgdx and it really frustrating when you can't figure out the right way to do something that you usally know how to do it in other circumstances. My problem is not about coding it, but to understanding the issue of Static or Enum in Android and how to avoid those in my asset manager.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the enum solution you reference?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why do you need it to be a static or enum? What's wrong with OOP?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it any other way... All tutorial that I found use ether a static method or an enum... And in fact both work very well... But I fall on these two documentations that suggest to avoid both of them! :/

Comment: Sounds like you should find different tutorials. Or at least not just use them as-is, but at least try to understand why they do it as they do it. Either way, you don't need `static` or `enum` to use any class (whether it is AssetManager or Screen or Sprite or GameObject etc. really doesnt matter for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a singleton that has a non-static asset manager instance and it's running pretty well (3 Android / 3 iOS games). So it should not be a problem.

Comment: I've try this but your getInstance() method has to be static to have acces to it? no?

Comment: Like in any singleton, you have only one instance of it. So the getInstance() method has to be static yes

Comment: Then this is my working solution I've already done it! The problem that make me hesitate about it was the fact in the documentation they said to avoid static asset manager or static method... Not quite sure of the difference between a static class and a static instance method since there both static.